# How to call the same function more than one time using parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters

```
<script>
function txtchk(as, tb) { 
//as is gonna be an asterisk
//tb is a an input type text
if (document.getElementById(tb).value == "") {
document.getElementById(as).style.display = "block";
}
else {
document.getElementById(as).style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

So when the tbox is empty, display the asterisk, else don't. The if statement is correct but how do I write the parameter?

```
<div class="b1">
<h>Book Name:</h>
<h class="astyle" id="asterisk1">*</h>
<div class="b2">
<input type="text" id="tbox1" oninput="txtchk(asterisk1, tbox1)">
//is using on input wrong?
</div>
```

Here I want the same to happen using the same function but different ids.

```
<div class="b1">
<h class="b1c">Description:</h>
<h class="astyle" id="asterisk2">*</h>
<div class="b2">
<textarea class="tarea" id="tbox2" oninput="txtchk(asterisk2, tbox2)">
</textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters must be string. Change your oninput like this

```
oninput="txtchk('asterisk2', 'tbox2')"
```